# Best pattern for configuration management Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, web-config

I always see that there are app.config's in dlls and then website has web.config.
At the run time mostly web.config passes data to all the portable libraries.

These configuration are passed as properties of portable library class. ConfigurationManager is used to get the values from config file.

Now the problem, In my current project they have configsectionhandler in webapp project/folder.

and my project folder structure is like

```
Main
 WebApp
 BusinessObject
 ThirdPartyWebserviceCall
```

and as usual webapp project has reference to BusinessObject  and BusinessObject   has reference to ThirdPartyWebserviceCall.

Now if I want to use configsectionhandler in ThirdPartyWebserviceCall I will have add a circular reference to

webapp.

Does this design seem ok? It looks realy flawed to me.

Is there other standard pattern to access configuration values in the libraries.